# Drop event not firing for stackpanel in wpf

Tags: wpf, stackpanel

I have a grid, which contains a Canvas and StackPanel on same level. I mean the StackPanel placed on the top of the canvas. The canvas contains multiple elements which should be dragable. And I have to handle the Drop event of the StackPanel. The drop event not working if  the stackpanel does not contain any child elements, even if I set the height for stackpanel. If I set the Background property for StackPanel it will work, but in this case the mousemove events of canvas child elements(below stackpanel) not working.

Here is the XAML

```
<Grid>
        <jas:DragCanvas 
            x:Name="dragCanvas"
            Grid.Row="1" 
            AllowDragging="{Binding ElementName=btnAllowDragging, Path=IsChecked}"
            AllowDragOutOfView="{Binding ElementName=btnAllowDragOutOfView, Path=IsChecked}"
            >
            <Ellipse
                Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Bottom="100"
                Width="65" Height="70">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.75" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
        </jas:DragCanvas>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
            <Border DockPanel.Dock="Left" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
                <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Drop="StackPanel_Drop" AllowDrop="True">
                    <Border Height="100" Width="100" Background="Red"></Border>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
```